# Validating power analysis

Tags: t-test, experiment-design, statistical-power, ab-test

I'm currently running some experiments in web. The main idea is to validate the impact in some conversion metrics. The typical funnel we have is: Traffic -> Signup -> some Activation event.

Our metric of interest is the CVR of some Activation Event. Let's assume a:

Traffic -> Event CVR = 1%

Signup -> Event CVR = 25%

The change in web will happen at the **traffic**, that means I can't split sellers to Control / Treatment at the Signup phase.

Now, I want to get calculate the power sample using Evans Calculator in web, and here's my question:

Which CVR should I use? The one from traffic or I can leverage the one from Signup even when the split is happening at the traffic?

Once I have the sample size, this sample size means which subjects? Traffic/Signups? Or a combination of Traffic/Signups + Event?

Ex. Using data from above, the required sample for Traffic -> Event CVR for a 50% lift (power at 0.8 and alpha 0.05) is 6,650. But 6,650 what, traffic?

Note: I know that people LOVES to correct people in Stack exchange, and with good reasons, but I'm not asking for complex things like moving to Bayes, Sequantial Testing, or that this is not even a suitable A/B test. I just want my questions to be clarify.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't quite follow what you want to study or show. Is it this? For every 100 visitors (traffic) you get 1 activation. For every 4 sign-ups you get 1 activation.  In both cases you want to be able to detect a 100% *relative* increase (so from 1% to 2% of visitors, or 25% to 50% of sign-ups). Without info on how traffic relates to sign-up we can only consider these separately, and any sample size will be for the rate you are conditioning on (e.g. the $n$ needed to go from 1 to 2% visitors -> events will be expressed in visitors, for 25 to 50% of sign-ups in sign-ups).

Comment: Yep, just like you mention. Exactly that. But, the relation is this:

Treatment happens at the traffic step. And also, the funnel of a visitors is:

Traffic -> Signup -> Activation. That's how traffic and signups are related.

Comment: I see, but to link a sample size from traffic to sign-up you'd have to know how many of your visitors *sign* *up*. Anyway, to get 80% power at 5% alpha for comparing the proportions 0.01 vs. 0.02 I get a sample size of ~2,400 per group under normal approximation (perhaps not ideal so close to the parameter boundary). That means you'd be powered when 'treating' 4,800 visitors 50/50, *if* they then also sign up at equal rates (big if).

Comment: I have all the numbers. Visitors, how many of them signups, and how many of them convert. So, you say I need to get the sample from visitors to convert, and mainly 'forget' signups? And this because the treated observations is the traffic?

Just for more context, my metric of interest is the convert event rate.

Comment: No, my point is that if your treatment already affects sign-up, you cannot conclude as much about the subsequent activation (because your two sets split up at the 'traffic' stage are no longer comparable). You can get by this if you condition on a sample size of sign-ups (e.g. I will randomly 'treat' traffic until I get 60 sign-ups per group, that should let you see 25% vs. 50% *in* *the* *sign-up* *subgroup*), or you can even consider both phases, but it's not likely that the sample size will be the same for both questions.

Comment: Uff, get more confused. At the end, I just want to be able to detect an effect on the activation event and the treatment happens at the traffic. 

Still don’t know which benchmark to use…